# Combining p values using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, p-value

I have to combine p values and get one p value.
I'm using scipy.stats.combine_pvalues function, but it is giving very small combined p value, is it normal?

e.g.:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> p_values_list=[8.017444955844044e-06, 0.1067379119652372, 5.306374345615846e-05, 0.7234201655194492, 0.13050605094545614, 0.0066989543716175, 0.9541246420333787]
>>> test_statistic, combined_p_value = scipy.stats.combine_pvalues(p_values_list, method='fisher',weights=None)
>>> combined_p_value
4.331727536209026e-08
```

As you see, **combined_p_value is smaller than any given p value in the p_values_list**?
How can it be?

Thanks in advance,
Burcak

Comment: What do you want to achieve when combining the p-values? Also, please consider that you may want to do some [multiple comparison correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).

Answer (score 4):

It is correct, because you are testing all of your p-values come from a random uniform distribution. The alternate hypothesis is that at least one of them is true. Which in your case is very possible.

We can simulate this, by drawing from a random uniform distribution 1000 times, the length of your p-values:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import combine_pvalues
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

random_p = np.random.uniform(0,1,(1000,len(p_values_list)))
res = np.array([combine_pvalues(i,method='fisher',weights=None) for i in random_p])
plt.hist(fisher_p)
```

[image]

From your results, the chi-square is 62.456 which is really huge and no where near the simulated chi-square above.

One thing to note is that the combining you did here does not take into account directionality, if that is possible in your test, you might want to consider using stouffer's Z along with weights. Also another sane way to check is to run simulation like the above, to generate list of p-values under the null hypothesis and see how they differ from what you observed.

[Interesting paper but maybe a bit on the statistics side](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06897.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means an expert in this field, but am interested in your question. Following some reading of [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method#Relation_to_Stouffer.27s_Z-score_method) it seems to me that the `combined_p_value` tells you the likelihood of all p-values in the list been obtained under the same null-hypothesis. Which is very unlikely considering two extremely small values.
Your set has two extremely small values: 1st and 3rd. If the thought process I described is correct, removing any of them should yield a much higher `p-value`, which is indeed the case:
remove 1st: p-value of `0.00010569305282803985`
remove 3rd: p-value of `2.4713196031837724e-05`
In conclusion, I think that this is a correct way of interpreting the meta-analysis that `combine_pvalues` actually describes.

Comment: I'm curuous. From the wiki page, from which sentences  did you conclude that combined_p_value is the likelihood of all p-values in the list? Thanks.

Comment: I was reading through the "Interpretation section", namely `Fisher's method is typically applied to a collection of independent test statistics, usually from separate studies having the same null hypothesis. The meta-analysis null hypothesis is that all of the separate null hypotheses are true. The meta-analysis alternative hypothesis is that at least one of the separate alternative hypotheses is true. ` Therefore I interpreted the `combined_p_value` as a likelihood of the statement that all p_values were obtained under the same null-hypothesis been true.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to understand whether changing the mehod helps getting a more realistic p-value. By more realistic p-value, I mean considering majority of the p values. If most of them > 0.05, I would not expect a combined p value <= 0.05.

Comment: I would think that if the rate at which very small values (compared to most of them) appear is high (it is 1/3 in your data), then it is unlikely that they were obtained from the data under the same null-hypothesis (for example generated through from the same distribution). For example you toss a coin 100 times for 9 sets, get about 50/50 heads to tails (calculate p values), and then 1 set of 100 times yields 90 heads and 10 tails. Odds that this 1 set was obtained with the same coin as previous 9 is very low, hence `combined_p` should also be very low if that 1 set is counted.